# How to Append Text in logical manner, etc

Tags: java, file-handling

I'm experimenting on how to create a sign-up page using file handling, which will result into a text file: "database.txt". The first time you fill out the requirements. The results are fine but when you register again for the second time, it just append it and not setting it the way I like it and I like it to be it like this way.

I have searched for similar problems like this in various websites, links, but I can't seem to understand it.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filepath = "C:\\Users\\Sparda\\Desktop\\Database.txt";

    try {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath,  true);

        System.out.println("Enter Username");
        String user = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Password");
        String pass = input.nextLine();

        String data = user + (",") + pass;

        fos.write(data.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Registered Successfully!");

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException: " + ex.toString());
    }

    catch (IOException ioe) {

        System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.toString());

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

}

The actual output is:

## Patrick Archie, BuyainAshley,Flames

While my expected output should be:

## Patrick Archie, Buyain

## Ashley, Flames

Comment: `fos.write("\n".getbytes());` add this statement above the `fos.write(data.getBytes());`

Answer (score 1):

You can write instead `String data = user + (",") + pass + ("\n");`

Comment: @PatrickNarsicoBuyain It is better to use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `"\n"`.